# is it possible to toggle between audio & video recording

Tags: javascript, audio, video-streaming, getusermedia

Is it possible when user want to record either audio/video when permission is given like
***({audio:true,video:true})***

```
 if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio:true, video: true }).then(function (stream) {
            if (recorder == null) {

                recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);


                recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', onRecordingReady);
            }
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        })
         .catch(function (err) {
              alert(err)
         });;
    };
```

the problem is i have two radio button one is for audio record selection and another one is for video record selection since its very hard and complicated to use mediarecorder two times in a single page i have goten here stucked can somebody give a sujjetion fo this?Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case?  If it's a short-term thing, you can `mute` the audio or video tracks.  If it's more long-term, it would be better to actually stop one of the tracks to save power.  I think you could use `applyConstraints()` in this case, but I haven't tried it.  Also, it's typical that once a user gives permission, subsequent permission is automatically given, so I don't think this is as much of a problem in the first place.

Comment: what u mean by ```applyConstraints()``` can u provide an example?

Comment: Nevermind, `applyConstraints()` is on the track, so I don't think that would work.  The other advice is still valid though, and if you would clarify what specifically you need, we could provide a good answer.